# Setting width and height of images with jquery in webkit browsers

Tags: jquery, image, browser, webkit

I have an image with mypic class

I'm using the load event to set the width and height of this image:

```
$(window).load(function() { 
    //Here I calculate final w and h  
    $('.mypic').css("width",w);
    $('.mypic').css("height",h);
    $('.mypic').height(h);
    $('.mypic').width(w);
});
```

In firefox I have no problem at all but in webkit browsers the height is not set and I don't know why. It's strange since the width is set without problems. Don't know what happens with safari and chrome.
Am I missing something? Could anybody help me?

Thankyou very much.

Comment: How are you going to calculate `w` & `h` ? please provide the code  you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(function() {
   //put your code here
  $('.mypic').css({
    'width': w,
    'height': h
  });
});
```

I'm doing a few thing here:

Encapsulating it all in a function and passing it to the jQuery object ($) will make sure it runs when the document loads (another handy use of $).

You can make one call to CSS with a JSON object of the attributes you want to set.

Oh, and setting the CSS height and calling .height(h) are identical except for their return value (http://api.jquery.com/height/) and, as you're not using the return value, you don't need to call both.

Anyways, tested and it works in Chrome and Safari.

Comment: Ok!! I see what you say, but the piece of code where I write "//Here I calculate final w and h  " needs to be executed once the page is loaded, with the image, because I get the actual width and height of the image before  resizing it taking into account the width and height of the browser window... I copy paste the whole code if it helps.

Comment: $(window).load(function() { 
 //Calculate values of height and width for the central image
 var totalWidth=$(window).width(); 
 var totalHeight=$(window).height(); 
 var sum= 510;//primary=248 + primaryRight=212 + margin=50
 var maxWidth=totalWidth-sum;
 var maxHeight=totalHeight-30;
 var w=$('.slides2 img').width();
 var h=$('.slides2 img').height();
 if (w < h) {
    h = (h * maxWidth) / w;
    w = maxWidth;
   }
 else {
    w = (w * maxHeight) / h;
    h = maxHeight;
 }
  $('.mypic').css("width",w);
  $('.mypic').css("height",h);
 });

Comment: I've added a comment to the original code, just put your code there. As long as w and h are defined when you reach the css, it'll execute.

Comment: Doing the way you say, using $(function() {   ... 
If I put an alert(w); right after var w=$('.slides2 img').width(); I get 0 with safari...

Comment: "Wrong use of the load function" - [wrong](http://api.jquery.com/load/): `Note: The event handling suite also has a method named .load(). Which one is fired depends on the set of arguments passed.`

Comment: @EMMERICH - His use of .load is **perfectly fine**.

Comment: Yeah doing that. Updated my post as well although I hadn't seen load used like that. Thanks for the downvote xx